# Какое есть слово для обозначения смешения с положительным результатом?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, синонимы, смысл

Например я с утра смешиваю чай и молоко, чай вкусный, молоко вкусное, чай с молоком ещё вкуснее(иначе бы я их не смешивал), следовательно чай и молоко хорошо ...... ! Что? Что они хорошо? Какое слово здесь должно быть.
Или например при смешении негров и китайцев получается более красивая раса людей, значит раса китайцев и раса негров хорошо ...... ! Что?

**сочетаются** - не подходит, потомучто в моём понимании, хорошо сочетаются, это хорошо комбинируются, например синий и красный цвета хорошо сочетаются, значит платье раскрашенное в красную и синию полоску будет красивым, это слово подразумевает комбинирование, дискретность, но не подразумевает смешивание, а если синий и красный при смешении дают ещё более красивый цвет, фиолетовый! то тогда синий и красный хорошо ...... ! Что? Что они хорошо? Какое слово здесь должно быть.

**соответствует** - тоже не подходит, соответствовать могут только не равнозначные объекты, например чай хорошо соответствует завтраку, а макароны обеду. Негры соответствуют африке, а китайцы азии.

**совместимы** - тоже не подходит, потомучто совместимость подразумевает взаимодействие, для этого эти объекты должны прежде всего действовать, молоко с огурцом могут быть плохо совместимы, потомучто они в кишечнике плохо провзаимодействуют и будет понос.
Или например негры и китайцы хорошо совместимы, это значит что они не конфликтуют вместе.

Comment: Встречается неформальное "смешабельные". Более солидное слово придётся придумывать. Если по аналогии с фотогеничностью (слово французского происхождения), то продукты в смеси могли бы быть "меланжегеничны" :)

Comment: Я могу понять безнадёжные проблемы с пунктуацией. Но как можно дважды в тексте написать слитно "потому что"? И проигнорировать подсказку от проверки орфографии.

Comment: Если не заниматься словотворчеством, то нужно искать способ выразить свою мысль другими словами. Чай и молоко дают вкусную смесь, а китайцы и негры — красивое потомство. Кстати, Вы тут "смешали" смешение рас и смешивание продуктов.

Comment: да но я то имею ввиду, более красивое потомство чем они сами.
>>чай вкусный, молоко вкусное, чай с молоком ещё вкуснее(иначе бы я их не смешивал).

Comment: Не просто положительный результат, а превосходящий по каким-от параметрам исходный материал?  Не думаю, что задача выразить такую мысль одним словом имеет решение.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, подойдут "гармонировать" или "согласоваться".

ГАРМОНИРОВАТЬ. Быть в согласии, в соответствии с кем-, чем-л.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего подходит слово "сочетание".

В словаре В. Даля есть более старое слово "СОЧЕТАВАТЬ". Значение: "СОЧЛЕНЯТЬ, сочленить что с чем-либо, союзить, соединять, связать, сцепить, совокуплять, особенно связывать звеном, не наглухо. Остов сочленяют проволочными связками. Члены общества сочленены круговым союзом. -ся, страдат. или возвр. по смыслу. Бедренная кость сочленяется с тазом вертлюгом, лежащим в глубокой ямине. Сочлененье, действ. по глаг. | Сгиб или сустав, мыщелка, вертлюг, навеска, петля, звено, стык двух частей, членов, подвижная связь их. Сочлен м. член, общее с кем, с прочими; член всякого общества, в отношении к товарищам."

В математике (точнее, комбинаторике) "сочетание" - то, что Вы  отбросили как неподходящее. Но русский язык и комбинаторика - немного разные инструменты, по моему скромному мнению. Не сочтите за наглость.

Comment: *В математике (точнее, комбинаторике) "сочетание" - то, что Вы отбросили как неподходящее.* — Вот Вам [ссылка для самообразования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).